# innerHTML auto-unescapes parts of HTML string?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, escaping

I have to inject a string of html code containing inline event handlers into an element using innerHTML. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById('some-div')
  .innerHTML = '<button onclick="alert(\'&lt;html&gt;\');">&lt;html&gt;</button>';
```

I expected to get this result:

```
<button onclick="alert('&lt;html&gt;');">&lt;html&gt;</button>';
```

but the actual DOM looks like this:

```
<button onclick="alert('<html>');">&lt;html&gt;</button>';
```

Why is the inline event handler part automatically unescaped by the browser? Can this be prevented without double-escaping?

Comment: You are feeding the text you assign to `.innerHTML` to the HTML parser in the browser. It sees your HTML escapes and interprets them.

Comment: Also doesn't your code work as written?

Comment: Could could add another level or encoding by doing `'&amp;lt;html&amp;gt;'` - but this can get ugly and unreadable pretty fast

Comment: @Pointy, makes sense. I somehow thought that the alert would show the escaped version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the HTML data to the browser by setting Element.innerHTML, the browser must interpret/parse the HTML to render it. Even though it doesn't specifically render the onclick property, it must still resolve the encoding. As Chris Barr said, you have to re-encode the string so that when the browser parses it, it will parse into the correct version.

Using a simple HTML encoder like https://opinionatedgeek.com/codecs/htmlencoder ,  you can re-encode the string and it should return "&lt;html&gt;".